# jQuery Carousel showing half of next and prev image with arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Anybody knows a jQuery carousel that can achieve a look like this? Slideshow that shows half of next and prev image with left/right arrows. Here's a screenshot below:

Here's a screenshot link: http://screencast.com/t/4BvfySsn

Comment: This site has similar to what you're looking for - you might have to modify it to have gaps between the main image and the left/right images; they also have so much more. http://www.jssor.com/demos/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.html edit: this isn't an answer, because it was the first result for my google query.

Comment: I actually already saw that one but was thinking there might be something better as if I add gaps then the left/right image will not be that visible anymore. If possible the next/prev image are showing 50% of image. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, well I'm not at a PC, or I'd check out how easy it is to modify, but just fyi, it's better to put things like that (things you've already found/steps you've already taken) in your question, it will help us to utilize our time to come up with better answers for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark. Yes, right now I'm working on that to suit my needs.